# Not able to see logs in log file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, log4j, testng

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
<param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
<param name="Append" value="true" />
<param name="File" value="logfile.log"/>
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m %n" />
</layout>
</appender>
<root>
<level value="INFO"/>
<appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

**This is the log4j xml file I am using, not able to see logs in logfile**

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by replacing the correct package "import org.apache.log4j.Logger"